# Populating listbox with files to include creation date

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I am attempting to populate a listbox with the contents of a directory. I have it populating but I need the creation date/time included in the list.

This is what I have so far:

```
  var filter = Path.GetFileName(GlobalVariables.EbillFile);
  listBox_Restore.DataSource = Directory.GetFiles(GlobalVariables.EbillBackupDirectory, $"{filter}.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
```

It gives me this:

[ListBox Contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEmaG.png)

How do I go about adding the date to this list? Should I be using a different control?

Comment: You probably want to use [`ListView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/listview-control-windows-forms) in `Detail` view, where you can add columns

Comment: [Directory.GetFiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_Directory_GetFiles_System_String_System_String_System_IO_SearchOption_) `Returns the names of files (including their paths) that match the specified search pattern in the specified directory, using a value to determine whether to search subdirectories`, nothing more. `File.GetCreationTime` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.getcreationtime?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_File_GetCreationTime_System_String_)

Comment: @HenrikHansen ok thank you, I'll check out listview!

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ Is there a better option to getting the filenames and creation dates then?

Comment: You need the date right, please see the link I posted. This has nothing to do with a `listview` control or any other control... Controls are for viewing, manipulating etc. data, not getting the data you need.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ Just for clarity, I'll need to get my list then GetCreationTime on each file, then populate my ListView?

Comment: Yes, that is correct, or you can do it for each file in one go. Also IMHO look at `Directory.EnumerateFiles` which returns an `IEnumerable` which can be lazily evaluated for the most part.

Comment: You can also use **IExplorerBrowser** (I had posted a sample with P/Invoke a few weeks ago), the Shell built-in interface/control to fill automatically the list of files : [Test IExplorerBrowser](https://i.ibb.co/sPQfNPq/IExplorer-Browser.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [`DirectoryInfo.GetFiles()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.getfiles?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_DirectoryInfo_GetFiles_System_String_) to get more information about each file - for instance created date, last used date, size etc.

And then use a [ListView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/listview-control-windows-forms) to show the result.

Comment: Updated your link to `GetFiles` so it actually takes a user there.